# Unidirectionally sync Android SQLite database from external MySQL database

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization

I have a large local SQLite database in my app. I need to keep it up to date with a MySQL database. I was thinking of generating some kind of XML file with the changes and then having the client download that and use it to update the local database. Records are created and deleted with each update. Is there a better way to do this? How should I go about this? I am really open to taking any route at this point.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Your method sounds good. I'd specifically use JSON, but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: @Benito The only thing I'm not sure of is deleted records. I guess I could send just the primary key with no other data and then it would to delete that record. I still have to figure out how to generate such a file. That and the processing it on the client end seems like it is getting more complicated than it needs to be, but I don't know if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost a year old, but this is how I did it in case anyone stumbles upon this.

-Have a MySQL database that holds all the changes
-When a change is added, it is generated with a Unix timestamp
-A column exists as a boolean for "deleted"

-PHP page takes timestamp as a URL variable
-returns all changes after that timestamp as a .CSV

-Application downloads .CSV, parses it, and updates its local SQLite database

Simple as that, works great.